# Merge row values from separate tables into one column. [SQL]

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

Hi I am just learning SQL and i am trying to retrieve some data from multiple tables and cannot get it to display how I would like it, so i am just wondering if this is possible or not, and if so could someone suggest a method, see below:

```
    Table1:                     Table2:                     Table3

    Package       Licenses      Package       Licenses      Package      Licenses
    ======================      ======================      =====================
    Product1         20         Product1         15         Product1        0
    Product2         15         Product2         5          Product2        5
    Product3         10         Product3         10         Product3        0
```

I would like the values in the Licenses columns to be added to each other according to the package name and it to display something like this if possible:

```
    Package       Licenses
    ======================
    Product1         35
    Product2         25
    Product3         20
```

If someone could let me know how this could be done, if such a thing is even possible please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT Package, SUM(Licences) as TotalLicences
  FROM (
        SELECT Package, Licences FROM Table1
         UNION ALL
        SELECT Package, Licences FROM Table2
         UNION ALL
        SELECT Package, Licences FROM Table3
       ) AS AllLicences
 GROUP BY Package
```

Comment: Much appreciated, seems obvious now its been laid out in front of me.

Answer (score 2):

It's the `UNION ALL` clause and `GROUP BY` statement you need researching.

The gist of the solution is to

- combine all rows from all tables using a `UNION ALL`
- put the results into a subselect
- calculate the total licenses by using a `GROUP BY` and the `SUM` aggregated function over the results of the subselect

**SQL Statement**

```
SELECT Package, SUM(Licenses) AS Licenses
FROM   (
         SELECT Package, Licenses FROM Table1 UNION ALL
         SELECT Package, Licenses FROM Table2 UNION ALL
         SELECT Package, Licenses FROM Table3
       ) t
GROUP BY
       Package
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `union` to create a view of all licences, and `sum` them:

```
select  Package
,       sum(Licences) as Licences
from    (
        select  Package
        ,       Licences
        from    Table1
        union all
        select  Package
        ,       Licences
        from    Table2
        union all
        select  Package
        ,       Licences
        from    Table3
        ) as SubQueryAlias
group by
        Package
```